# Can't set headers after they're sent NodeJs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

I'm a little new to the Mean stack and I've been trying to experiment a bit with http requests with a mongo database that has a collection for storing feedback

I'm repeatedly getting an error of "Can't set headers after they're sent" in my console.

Here's the code for my function

```
module.exports.saveFeedback = function(req, res, callback) {
    var newFeedback = new feedback();
    newFeedback.overallAppExperience = req.body.overallAppExperience;
    newFeedback.save(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err, null);
        } else {
            return callback(null, result);
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the code for my route

```
app.post('/feedback', function(req,res){
  feedback.saveFeedback(req,res, function(err,result){
      if(err){
          res.status(500).send(err);
          return;
      }
      else{
          res.status(200).send(result);
          return;
      }
  });
});
```

Here's the code for my controller

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('feedbackController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, 
$http){
$scope.overallAppExperience=null;
$scope.feedbackSubmit=function()
{
var data={
    overallAppExperience:$scope.overallAppExperience
}
$http.post('/feedback', data)
            .then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
                },function(response){
        console.log(response);
                })
 }]);
```

Here's the issue - The entry I make via submitting the feedback form on the html page gets logged on to the mongo database. The same doesn't get displayed on the web console in my browser.

This is the entry in the web console and it corresponds to the error function being invoked in the promise.

```
Object { data: null, status: -1, headers: wd/<(), config: Object, statusText: "" }
```

Also, the error message in the console mentions these two lines as problematic: 
One in my feedback Function (Line 8)

```
return callback(null,result);
```

And the other in my routes function (Line 8)

```
res.status(200).send(result);
```

I have read similar posts about such errors and all of them talk about something to do with the return statements. I've tried playing around with the return statements by removing them and adding them again. However, the same error persists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error "Can't set headers after they're sent NodeJs" is caused when your code tries to send more than one response to the same request.  It is usually caused by mistaken asynchronous code that sends a response both in the async callback and outside the async callback.  I do not see a cause for that error in the code you've shown so I suspect it is caused by some other code you have not shown.

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with the error, but your your angular code block is missing a `}` to close this function definition `$scope.feedbackSubmit=function() { ...`.

Comment: Yeah. I've made that change. For some reason, the code seems to be working fine in Chrome but throws up errors in Firefox.

Comment: What exact errors are you seeing only in Firefox?  Client-side errors?  Or server-side errors?

Comment: Both, client side and server. This is the client side error object that gets logged in the web console: 
Object { data: null, status: -1, headers: wd/<(), config: Object, statusText: "" }

For the server side, it's the error that I've mentioned in the question. 

For Chrome, the code executes smoothly and there are no errors on either side. The appropriate response object also gets logged on the web console.